# Create an empty text file

Tags: go, io

I've been reading and googling all over but I can't seem to find this simple answer.

I have a function that reads a file, but if the files doesn't exists it panics. What I want to do is a function that before reading, checks if the files exists, and if not, it creates an empty file. Here is what I have.

```
func exists(path string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err == nil {
        return true, nil
    }
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false, nil
    }
    return true, err
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Don't try to check the existence first, since you then have a race if the file is created at the same time. You can open the file with the `O_CREATE` flag to create it if it doesn't exist:

```
os.OpenFile(name, os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but how can I set flags to `ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)` ?

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio You can't pass flags to ioutil.ReadFile, but you could just use os.OpenFile with ioutil.ReadAll

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio: you don't. `ioutil.ReadFile` is just a convenience function to call `os.Open` and `iotuil.ReadAll`. If you need more control, you create your own similar function.

Comment: Doesn't this leak a file descriptor?

Comment: Ah, never mind, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595507/476074 they are closed automatically.

Comment: @AndreKR: If you're worried about "leaking" file descriptors, you can't depend on the finalizer because finalizers are never guaranteed to run, but you should be closing the file anyway. Using `os.O_CREATE` to open a file and create it if it doesn't exist has nothing to do with making sure you call "Close"

Comment: Seems you are right, if there's no memory pressure it might never be GC'd. In that case I think the answer to "how to create an empty file" should include the call to `Close()`.

Comment: Can this be used to create directories?

Answer (score 7):

Just trying to improve the excellent accepted answer.

It's a good idea to check for errors and to `Close()` the opened file, since file descriptors are a limited resource. You can run out of file descriptors much sooner than a GC runs, and on Windows you can run into file sharing violations.

```
func TouchFile(name string) error {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return file.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OpenFile` function is the best way to do this, but here is another option:

```
package main
import "os"

func create(name string) (*os.File, error) {
   _, e := os.Stat(name)
   if e == nil { return nil, os.ErrExist }
   return os.Create(name)
}

func main() {
   f, e := create("file.txt")
   if os.IsExist(e) {
      println("Exist")
   } else if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   f.Close()
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#ErrExist