# Why doesn't ParseMultipartForm leak file handles?

Tags: go

I’ve got an http endpoint which calls `net/http.(*Request).FormFile` to read a file uploaded. I noticed the returned `*multipart.File` is never closed with `Close()`. That is fine for small files as it is a no-op, but It appears that https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go#L1369 `r.ParseMultipartForm` will copy the file out of memory and into a temp file if the file is larger than 32MB. You can see the `os.Open` call here: https://golang.org/src/mime/multipart/formdata.go?s=3614:3656#L146

AFAICT this would leak file handles, but when I examine the process, I do not see leaking file handles. Where is this cleaned up?

UPDATE: Here is a complete program for testing: https://play.golang.org/p/79_kt46t1PQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multipart.Form` declares a `RemoveAll()` method, which calls `os.Remove(fh.tmpfile)`.

This method is called either on an error during `multipart.Reader.ReadForm` or after the request has been served:

```
    if w.req.MultipartForm != nil {
        w.req.MultipartForm.RemoveAll()
    }
```

The above is located at https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1957

**Edit:**

Actually you might be on to something. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20253) mentioning this. In the issue [it is noted](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20253#issuecomment-373919611) that `RemoveAll` gets called at the end of the request, but the files are reportedly still there.

As you also commented, this might be related to the `os.Remove` call being implemented (on Unix) with `unlink` syscall, which:

> If the name was the last link to a file but any processes still
> have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the
> last file descriptor referring to it is closed.

So to wrap up, I think you are supposed to call `Close()` yourself on the `multipart.File`, as suggested in the same thread:

```
file, _, _ := r.FormFile("file")
defer file.Close()
```

It could be a documentation bug, though some could argue that closing files after usage is obvious, though in this particular case, the docs might be more explicit. Anyway, at this point I guess you could ask for further clarification on the linked issue.

Comment: I found that, and that will remove the file, but in Linux, removed files aren't closed. When my server process exits the file will be closed and disk freed, but until that happens the file is still open. Where is the file closed? Or is my server leaking file handles and I just don't see it?

Comment: The thing I can't figure out is how the file is getting closed. I made a server that is particularly slow to complete requests and I use lsof to see the file open and once the request is completed, the file is closed and removed. There must be a line of code somewhere doing it, but I cannot find it.

Comment: ahha! https://stackoverflow.com/a/29518882/16998 Open files do have finalizers attached. That is how it is being closed.