# Close() invocations and the garbage collector

Tags: go, garbage-collection

In Go, interfaces that use resources like network connections usually have a `Close()` method that disposes of these resources.

Now I wonder what would happen if the associated structs implementing the interface get garbage-collected without `Close` having been invoked.
Will the OS keep the network connection / file descriptor / whatever open? Will the garbage collector do something or will something even prevent it from touching that struct?

I.e.

```golang
conn, _ := net.DialTCP(network, laddr, raddr)
// do stuff, then
conn = nil
// forgot to invoke `Close()`!!
// what happens now?
```

Comment: Yes, if you want the connection to be closed, you must close the connection.

Comment: os will keep the file descriptors for non closed connections, which is going to be freed when the program exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such closeable resources may have finalizers set with [`runtime.SetFinalizer`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#SetFinalizer), [for example the `netFD`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/fd_posix.go#L33) of `TCPListener`:

```
runtime.SetFinalizer(fd, (*netFD).Close)
```

This should not be a reason for omitting to call `Close()` to free resources, also because there is no guarantee that the finalizer will be called or when:

> The finalizer is scheduled to run at some **arbitrary** time after the program can no longer reach the object to which obj points. There is **no guarantee** that finalizers will run before a program exits, so typically they are useful only for releasing non-memory resources associated with an object during a long-running program.

Call `Close()` to make sure the resources are freed.

Related:

- [Which objects are finalized in Go by default and what are some of the pitfalls of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595457)

Comment: Moreover, the garbage collector paces itself based on Go memory usage — not kernel resources. So if you _were_ to rely on the finalizer to close the connections, you could very well run out of file descriptors before the collector decides to run again.

Answer (score 2):

Os will keep the file descriptors for non-closed connections, which is going to be freed once the program exits.